# Validator message disappeared after postback in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I click submit button without enter data error message appears for required fields. But when I select from radio buttons due to its ***autopostback*** message disappears whereas I want this message to show until I entered data in that fields.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="contactName" runat="server" CssClass="texrbox" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="nameValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name Required" ControlToValidate="contactName" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

This is working fine until radio button causes postback.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="contact" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CausesValidation="false" ForeColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="contact_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Submitter" Value="Submitter"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Following" Value="Following"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Now please help me how can I use ***postback*** and also my message not disappear.

Comment: Did you tried CausesValidation="true" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page post back, do this on page load.

```
 Page.Validate();
  if (Page.IsValid)
  {
     //TO DO
  }
```